# vTaskPrioritySet needs extra TaskHandle_t to function

Tags: stm32, keil, freertos

Im using STM32F429I-DISC1 and Keil uVision v5

Ive written a simple example to demonstrate task priority setting using handles however the code only functions if I first delcare an unused TaskHandle_t (By functioning I mean the red LED blinks whilst the green LED stays static). When the unused TaskHandle_t is removed both LEDs blink (ie task priority is the same for both tasks)

```
/*

Simple blinky program converted to FreeRTOS
GnLed: PG13
RdLed: PG14

*/


#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"              // Keil::Device:STM32Cube HAL:Common
#include "FreeRTOS.h"                   // ARM.FreeRTOS::RTOS:Core
#include "task.h"                       // ARM.FreeRTOS::RTOS:Core


#define gn_led GPIO_PIN_13
#define rd_led GPIO_PIN_14

void GPIO_Init(void);
void vGnLedControllerTask(void* pvParam);
void vRdLedControllerTask(void* pvParam);

TaskHandle_t test; //When this line is added code functions as expected
TaskHandle_t rd_Handle, gn_Handle;

int main()
{
    GPIO_Init(); 

    xTaskCreate(vGnLedControllerTask,
                            "Green Led Controller",
                            100,
                            NULL,
                            1,
                            &gn_Handle
                            );

    xTaskCreate(vRdLedControllerTask,
                            "Red Led Controller",
                            100,
                            NULL,
                            1,
                            &rd_Handle
                            );

    vTaskStartScheduler();
    while(1){};
}

void vGnLedControllerTask(void* pvParam)
{
    while(1)
    {
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOG, gn_led);
        for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++){}
        vTaskPrioritySet(rd_Handle, 2);
    }
}

void vRdLedControllerTask(void* pvParam)
{
    while(1)
    {
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOG, rd_led);
        for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++){}
    }
}


void GPIO_Init(void)
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOG_CLK_ENABLE();
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOG, GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOG, &GPIO_InitStruct);
}
```

Comment: Try defining the red handle and green handle on separate lines.

Comment: I've tried that with the same effect. I've also tried setting them to null with no luck.

Comment: Is it possible the task names (like “Green Led Controller”) are too long? There’s a `#define` for the maximum size of a task name in `FreeRTOSConfig.h`. If you exceed the allowed size, you’ll be overwriting memory owned by something else, and this may wreak all sorts of havoc, including the behavior you’re seeing.